# What is a confidence interval for a population mean?

Tags: inference

I have been learning about the central limit theorem and confidence intervals from [this video](https://pt.coursera.org/lecture/inferential-statistics-intro/confidence-interval-for-a-mean-DA30M).

The instructor states that when all sample means are compiled it forms a normal distribution (according to the central limit theorem). She also states that the population mean (unknown) lies at the center of this distribution. She states that a confidence interval is constructed by taking a sample mean and adding 2 times the sample error (rule of thumb).

However, near the end of the video, she states that this formula is used for finding the "confidence interval of a population mean". How is this right? Aren't we taking a sample mean from the population? And when we construct a confidence interval from a sample, is it also based on the normal distribution? But how could it be, as a normal distribution is only made when numerous samples are taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are confused about the term "*confidence interval of a population mean*" since you only have the sample mean and construct a confidence interval based on the sample.

I would like to raise the question, what would you like to do with a "*confidence interval of the sample mean*"?

Once you have the sample, you *know* the sample mean, i.e. you should be 100% confident that the sample mean is one specific number. There is no need for a confidence interval for your sample mean.

What you *do not know*, is the population mean. However, you have at least an idea of it, since you have collected a sample from the population. Your best guess of the population mean is the sample mean, as simple as it is.

But are we 100% confident that the sample mean is the population mean? Of course, we are not. *How confident are we*? Well, there are several different approaches to answer that question, but probably the most famous way is to apply a mathematical procedure on your sample mean, which gives you an interval that captures in 95% of the cases the population mean.

This is called the confidence interval, and the mathematical procedure you have just seen in the video. To make this interval capture the population mean in actually 95% of the cases, you must rely on central limit theorem (or apply other methods).

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. In the last sentence you say "To make this interval capture the population mean in actually 95% of the cases, you must rely on central limit theorem", why do we have to rely on central limit theorem for it to capture the mean 95% of the time?

Comment: When dealing with this classic frequentist approaches, you must always think in the terms "what would happen if I repeated my study infinitely many times?". If central limit theorem applies, then your infinitely many sample means would follow a normal distribution. Since we know the normal distribution quite well, we can easily give the range where 95% of all values lie, i.e. mean +/- 2*SD. The "standard error" is nothing else than the theoretical standard deviation of the sample mean, based on CLT. It's theoretical because there is just one sample mean, of course, so it does not deviate.

Comment: If you cannot rely on CLT, then judging the confidence in your estimate becomes harder. You need to answer the question "what distribution does my estimate follow?", which is hard to tell if you have only one sample and therefore only one sample mean. One solution might be bootstrapping, to just name a popular buzzword.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just one more thing, I understand that we use a normal for all the sample means (forms a normal distribution due to CLT), but I am still a bit confused about how the normal distribution is used for samples. This website (https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/confidence-interval.html) at the section "Standard Normal Distribution" a normal distribution with the confidence interval values, so are confidence intervals made by a normal distribution or something? Thanks a lot

Comment: And why do we do z score times the margin of error, and not the standard deviation?

Comment: You're welcome! What you refer to as "margin of error" or "standard error" is nothing else than the standard deviation of your estimate. This standard deviation becomes smaller, the more precise the estimate is (e.g. because it is based on a very large sample, since then you would not expect it to deviate that much if you repeat your study), hence the confidence in this estimate becomes larger and the confidence interval becomes more narrow. When constructing the confidence interval, one usually assumes that the estimate is normally distributed which is often legit due to CLT.